# Obtain a group with desired properties using RandomEntity

Tags: random, entity, group-theory

This is my current try:

```
EntityValue[
  RandomEntity[
    EntityClass["FiniteGroup", {"Abelian" -> False, "Order" -> 24}], 
    10
  ], 
  "PermutationGroupRepresentation"
]
```

[image: Output containing some Missing["NotAvailable"] entries]

But as we can see above, I sometimes will get a group without `"PermutationGroupRepresentation"`. I want to avoid this case. So I change my code to the following:

```
EntityValue[
  RandomEntity[
    EntityClass[
      "FiniteGroup", 
      {"Abelian" -> False, "Order" -> 8, 
       "PermutationGroupRepresentation" -> (Not[MissingQ[#]]&)}
    ], 
    10
  ], 
  "PermutationGroupRepresentation"
]
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Have I made any mistakes?

Comment: Maybe try `FilteredEntityClass`?

Comment: I'm in unfamiliar territory here, but this seems to work:`RandomEntity[
 FilteredEntityClass["FiniteGroup", 
  EntityFunction[e, 
   And[Not[MissingQ[c["PermutationGroupRepresentation"]]], 
    24 == e["Order"], Not[e["Abelian"]]]]], 10]`

Comment: @lericr It's seems [miss still](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqYKM.png)

Comment: Spelling error, sorry. Replace the c with e.

Comment: @lericr Thank very much, It works now... It should be an answer. :)

Comment: Since I was unfamiliar with these functions, I wasn’t sure if it should be an answer. If no one comes up with something better, I’ll promote it.

Comment: @lericr Your approach in comments seems to answer the OP's question. Please convert it to a formal answer! If somebody else comes along with another approach, then eve better, but your should be preserved as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FilteredEntityClass` seems to do the trick:

```
RandomEntity[
  FilteredEntityClass[
    "FiniteGroup",
    EntityFunction[
      e,
      And[
        Not[MissingQ[e["PermutationGroupRepresentation"]]],
        24 == e["Order"],
        Not[e["Abelian"]]]]], 
  10]
```

Comment: Thank you for adding your answer (+1)